# GT7300 GeFORCE strange clock and memory

Tags: overclocking, nvidia-geforce

So last time I had problems with my graphics card and maybe I will have them in near future.
I have got GeForce7300 500MHZ clock and 700MHZ memory do you think that it's ok? 
Because I think it's to overclocked. Am I right or not?

Answer (score 1):

The 7300 GT has 500MHz Core clock speed & 700MHz memory clock. Nothing wrong there, a li'l higher than the reference 350MHz/350Mhz Core & memory clocks

Comment: Do you think that overclocking this card to 550 and 750 could damage it?

Comment: Without knowledge of what sort of cooling apparatus is there, I cannot comment. You can try increasing by 5Mhz increments, and run couple of 3DMark benchmarks after every increase to test for stability. If you see no artifacts or crashes, then the card is coping well